# Content Area Slipping Down To The Left of Left Sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have a problem with a left hand side affixed block region on my theme. The #content in this code slips down to the left of the sidebar first affixed block.

```
    <body class="html not-front logged-in two-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-616 node-type-group og-context og-context-node og-context-node-616">
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-medium navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-toggle row-fluid">
<aside id="sidebar-first" class="sidebar span2 hidden-phone">
<div class="region region-sidebar-first">
<div class="region region-sidebar-first-affix affix" style="width: 145px;">
</aside>
<div id="containerr">
<section id="content" class="span6">
<div class="region region-content">
</section>
<aside id="sidebar-second" class="sidebar span4 hidden-phone">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="container-wrapper">
<div id="sb-container">
</body>
```

CSS that i think affects it all is -

```
#sidebar-first > .region {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0A0A0A;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.region-sidebar-first-affix.affix {
    top: 20px;
}
.region-sidebar-first-affix.affix {
    top: 55px !important;
}

.affix {
    position: fixed;
}
```

You can view the code on this page if needs be [not a spam link as im deletin this domain soon](http://netmagpie.com/house-hill-photography)

All pointers much appreciated as it seems to be just a little outwith my CSS and Html knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: mmmmm maybe its the #containerr div thats messing it all up. I added that as the div name might suggest.

Comment: no i think its the <aside id="sidebar-first" class="sidebar span2 hidden-phone"> thats causing the problem. It doesnt seem want to 'go all the way to the botto'.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet of code is missing several closing tags and doesn't really illustrate the problem with your page.

I was able to correct the display on your page by changing the css for section#content.

You could write your css like so:

section#content {
    margin-left:19.5%;
    width: 54%
}

Comment: thanks rjones. Ive editted my original post and added the html again. I dont think that i am able to change the #content width as its reponsive. This would make things very strange i believe.

Comment: deleting my span6 etc code seems to have fixed it. i must have had all the widths herethere and everywhere

Comment: actually tel a lie it hasnt :(

Comment: There were widths specified in the page (I can no longer see the page though). Wouldn't using media queries handle responsive sizing issues, so when you were at below 768px (or whatever breakpoint you need) you could make the width 100%? The affixed content seemed to be hidden at the smaller viewport sizes if I recall correctly.

Comment: sorry Rick ive been away depressed about websites for a couple of days. Ill go turn my site back on to the public. Aye the sidebars are hidden on smaller resolutions. Its when vewing it on full res that the problems occur. It looks like a simple enough fix but for the life of me i just cant get it. I think its to do with the left sidebar. If i fill that up with content everything is ok. If it only has a block or two or if its justthe leftsidebar affixed then everything goes all errrrr 'tits up':(

Comment: Another approach, if you don't want to use a media query to reset the width to 100% in small viewports, is to change the source order of the page to put the second aside (#sidebar-second) before the section#content and use float:right on both of them.

Comment: the #sidebar-second is ok though rick is it not? actually i see what your saying Rick and that does seem to work. I cant seem to get the second sidebar to the right of the content though even though its after the #content. mmmmm its all because i added the #containerr div. Maybe i could take that out again and try to add it again. bah im depressed...nope im not let me go try...

Comment: <div id="containerr">

 
<?php print $breadcrumb ?><?php if ($tabs): ?>
                  
<?php if ($page['topmenu']): ?><?php print render($page['topmenu']) ?> <?php endif ?>
<div class="tabs"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div> 
     
                  <?php endif; ?><?php print $preface ?>



</div>

Comment: oooops. if i take that whole div out things work as hoped. i was originally just tryingto add a block region above the #content and #second-sidebar region and to the right of the #sidebar-first weird how it works on some pages and not others. there doesnt seem to be any rhyme nor reason to it

Comment: if i add a 'long' block to the #sidebar-first region then it seems to work ok too. It must be something to do with the #containerr region needing to have more #sidebar-first to accomodate it. Im not making much sense now.